# How is manifest.yaml generated?

Tags: ros, documentation, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to understand and even improve rosdoc_lite and have a question... let's take roscpp as an example.

Where is the landing page for http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/ generated from?

Back in the day we use to have manifest.xml files in every package that would do this, but looking at https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/indigo-devel/clients/roscpp this does not exist.

I see that now a manifest.yaml is generated, such as here:
http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/manifest.yaml

But how does the description get generated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199911/how-is-manifest.yaml-generated?/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The landing page is a doxygen mainpage: [see here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/ce75bf8d9c19f8337d2196d3d19f9ba8745e0583/clients/roscpp/include/ros/roscpp.dox)

The manifest.yaml is an internal data storage generated by rosdoc/rosdoc_lite and then rendered by the wiki. It's aggregated from various sources, depending on the package type. The description comes from the package.xml for catkin packages like roscpp.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1